# JQuery and Bootstrap based toaster

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

In my HTML page i have table in which each row, there is a check box.

My requirement is if more then one row is selected i.e. if the array length is 2, a toaster message has to be shown.

I got a use case there and it is,

1. if i select 2 rows(array length is 2), message is showing .
2. Then select 3rd row(array length is 3) and again deselect 3rd row(array length is 2 again).
3. Now also it shows the  message. Here i don't want that toast.

My approach is :

```
 $scope.toggleOne = function () {
        if ($scope.selectedUsers.length === 2) {
            showMessage();
        }
        for (var j = 0; j < $scope.users.length; j++) {
            if (!$filter('filter')($scope.selectedUsers, $scope.users[j].id, true).length) {
                $scope.selectAllCheckboxOfUsers = false;
                return;
            }
        }
        $scope.selectAllCheckboxOfUsers = true;
    }
```

Comment: try reading this page: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: 1. dont show message more then twice

Comment: 2. remember all selection and dont show if selection was already

Comment: 3. remember last selection when was message and dont show message if it same

Comment: you have to store previous selection. if previousSelectedUser.length is 3 and currentSelectedUser.length is 2 then don't call 'showMessage();'

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the message just when going from 1 selected to 2 selected, you can check for that:

```
var previousSelectedNum = 0;

$scope.toggleOne = function () {

    if ($scope.selectedUsers.length === 2 && previousSelectedNum === 1) {
        showMessage();
    }

    // ...

    previousSelectedNum = $scope.selectedUsers.length;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a flag such as,

```
var isMessageShown = false;
```

Then in your function use as,

```
$scope.toggleOne = function () {
    if($scope.selectedUsers.length === 1){
         isMessageShown = false;
    }
    if ($scope.selectedUsers.length === 2 && !isMessageShown) {
        isMessageShown = true;
        showMessage();
    }
    for (var j = 0; j < $scope.users.length; j++) {
        if (!$filter('filter')($scope.selectedUsers, $scope.users[j].id, true).length) {
            $scope.selectAllCheckboxOfUsers = false;
            return;
        }
    }
    $scope.selectAllCheckboxOfUsers = true;
}
```